# How JSDB generates .exe from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, executable

Take a look [here](http://www.jsdb.org/index.html).
It's a really neat project.
I am just wondering how do they generate exes out of javascript code.
I know they use TraceMonkey as their javascript engine.
Edit:
[Here you can find an example at the bottom of the page](http://www.jsdb.org/tutorial.html)

Comment: Where do you see the claim that they generate EXEs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like they just put the .js file into a zip container, and concatenate it onto the end of the jsdb executable. Apparently, when jsdb runs it checks for the .zip file and runs it. The JavaScript itself isn't compiled (except at runtime by the TraceMonkey engine), it's just included in the executable.